# Comparing arrays that have been stored as Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

A multipurpose field in an Object of type **ObjectHolder** contains an Object **obj**.  **obj** might store a wrapped primitive or an array of primitives.  How can we compare two **obj**s if they are arrays?  A simplified example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ObjectHolder {

    public Object obj;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectHolder oh1 = new ObjectHolder();
        oh1.obj = new int[]{ 3, 4, 5 };

        ObjectHolder oh2 = new ObjectHolder();
        oh2.obj = new int[]{ 3, 4, 5 };

        if (oh1.obj.getClass().isArray() && oh2.obj.getClass().isArray()) {
            System.out.println("We know both objects are arrays.");
            // System.out.println(Arrays.equals(oh1.obj, oh2.obj));
        }   
    }   

}
```

The commented-out line causes the compile to break.

Note- the array can be of any primitive type (or String), so simply casting it to **int[]** is not a convenient general solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two integer arrays in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897366/comparing-two-integer-arrays-in-java)

Comment: In which java version is this? I can't seem to find it

Comment: @Tibrogargan - I don't think so, here he's talking about ObjectHolder

Comment: @ItamarGreen Yes, he is: "How can we compare two objs if they are arrays?".  The ObjectHolder piece he's already got

Comment: What's the point in a class to hold an `Object` reference? Doesn't an `Object` reference already do that?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Tibrogargan You're missing the point that the arrays might not *be* `int[]` objects. They could be `float[]`, `boolean[]`, `String[]`, `Object[]`, `Long[]`, or anything else you can imagine. Read the last sentence of the question: *Note- the array can be of **any primitive type (or String)**, so simply casting it to int[] is not a convenient general solution.*

Comment: @AndyTurner Holders provide a means to return values from a method that also needs to return other values and/or return a success/failure.  i..e `ObjectHolder h = new ObjectHolder(); if (foo(h)) { ... doSomething(h.object); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case Java Reflections will do the job (idea from question [Java Array Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493711/java-array-comparison)):

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ObjectHolder {
    public Object obj;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {

        ObjectHolder oh1 = new ObjectHolder();
        oh1.obj = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };

        ObjectHolder oh2 = new ObjectHolder();
        oh2.obj = new int[] { 3, 4, 6 };

        if (oh1.obj.getClass().isArray() && oh1.obj.getClass().equals(oh2.obj.getClass())) {
            Class<?> c = oh1.obj.getClass();

            if (!c.getComponentType().isPrimitive()) {
                c = Object[].class;
            }

            Method m = Arrays.class.getMethod("deepEquals", c, c);
            System.out.println((Boolean) m.invoke(null, oh1.obj, oh2.obj));
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

I think the way @Andreas pointed out in his edited answer the following way might be a shorter, better and cleaner solution than using Java Reflections:

```
if(oh1.obj.getClass().isArray() && oh1.obj.getClass().equals(oh2.obj.getClass())) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(new Object[] { oh1.obj }, new Object[] { oh2.obj }))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Next, you verify that the arrays have the same component type by calling [`getComponentType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType--), then call the appropriate overload of [`Arrays.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#i42) (there are 9 of them).

**UPDATED**

Of course, it would be much easier to just call [`Arrays.deepEquals(Object[] a1, Object[] a2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-), since it already has all the logic of doing that.

```
if (Arrays.deepEquals(new Object[] { oh1.obj }, new Object[] { oh2.obj })) {
    // They are equal, though they may not be arrays
}
```

To quote the javadoc, where `e1 = oh1.obj` and `e2 = oh2.obj`:

> - `e1` and `e2` are both arrays of object reference types, and `Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2)` would return true
> - `e1` and `e2` are arrays of the same primitive type, and the **appropriate overloading** of `Arrays.equals(e1, e2)` would return true.
> - `e1 == e2`
> - `e1.equals(e2)` would return true.

Comment: Seems this would also work [for some objects] if the objects weren't arrays.